# Latitude And Longitude From Zip Code dynamically Using PHP

Tags: php

In my site when user create their account at that time they enter their zip code, & I have to store latitude, longitude of that zip code in database.
I am using this code to get latitude, longitude:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$_POST['zip']."&sensor=false";
            $result_string = file_get_contents($url);
            $result = json_decode($result_string, true);
            $result1[]=$result['results'][0];
            $result2[]=$result1[0]['geometry'];
            $result3[]=$result2[0]['location'];
            $_POST['latitude'] = $result3[0]['lat'];
            $_POST['longitude'] = $result3[0]['lng'];
$result = insert("stores",$_POST);
}
```

But `$_POST['latitude'] & $_POST['longitude']` variables are empty. it looks like this code does not execute. No issue with db query & db connection. can anyone help? What is wrong with me?

Comment: there is no code for storing in database here

Comment: As per above code  $_POST['latitude']  &  $_POST['longitude'] should have some value. but it returns empty. It is not returning any value that means there is some issue with this code not with db

Comment: I've tested and everything seems fine except last part $result = insert('stores', $_POST); are you using Wordpress or some other  CMS/framework? or is this insert your function and if it is, please post it here

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to fire query to save it in the DB,
from the above code you are getting 'lat' and 'long' correctly you just need to put it in a variable a fire query to mysql (assuming you are using mysql).

Comment: my db query is just fine, no issue with query. But I don't know if this code is execute or not but when I am trying to echo $_POST['latitude'] & $_POST['longitude'], these both variables are empty.